# convergence of the coefficients of lacunary series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fa.functional-analysis

I just want to find some standard reference to the following result: let $(a_k)_k$ be the sequence of coefficients of a lacunary Fourier series which converges to an $L_1(T)$ function in the sense of tempered distributions; then $(a_k)_k \in \ell_2$.

Can someone help on this? And make the statement more precise, if it needs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be stated, with copious references, and plenty of related results in Jean Pierre Kahane's survey Lacunary Taylor and Fourier series, Bulletin AMS 1964

Comment: Thanks! It seems to state more than what is actually proved in some of the references, but I have yet to check other references made there, in particular what seems to be the main one: the classic book on trigonometric series by Zygmund.

Answer (score 1):

This particular result can also be found as Theorem 1.4b in Chapter V of Katznelson's *Introduction to Harmonic Analysis* (2nd ed., Dover).

Of course much more is known, which I guess would be found or referenced in the survey article that Igor Rivin has already mentioned.